# Upgrade Windows 10 Home (non-N) to Education N?

Tags: windows-10, license, windows-activation, product-key

Cheers,

I've clicked myself an Education version key from my university's <s>MSDN-AA</s> <s>Dreamspark</s> Imagine platform. My regular Windows is an OEM key upgrade from Windows 8, non-N; the uni only offers N versions.

Trying to enter the key via activation leading to the product key change dialog yields error 0xC004F050; from what I can tell, it seems to think it's an invalid key.

Is this because I'm trying to upgrade from a non-N version? And regardless of cause, how should I proceed to have the Education version on my device?

Comment: do a clean install with the Edu N ISO and enter here the N product key. N and normal editions are 2 different products with 2 different keys

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid a complete reinstall, thanks though.

Comment: you could change registry in Home to Home N and now upgrade to Ent N, but I never tried this.